# What's the correct data design for recording the results of generic two player game?

Tags: database

Assume the game has two players.  Each player has a score and highest score wins.  A user table is self evident.  The first design I thought of is as follows:

match_id, user1_id, user2_id, score1, score2

The problem is suppose I want a quick way of ranking users by win %.  In the above table a single userid would be scattered between user1_id and user2_id.  It would seem to require multiple queries and seems messy.  The other way is to keep a separate stats table

user_id, winloss

This makes queries easy but doesn't seem theoretically correct because the stats table stores derive data.  Is there a way to solve this which involves a nice, clean theoretically correct data structure which is easy to query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about have one record for each user in a match? The primary key is then the combination of `match_id` and `user_id`. Also include a boolean `winner` field.

> match_id, user_id, score, winner

Though not part of your requirement, this also easily scales up to more players.

Querying win % is simply a matter of:

```
SELECT winner, count(winner) FROM match_results
WHERE user_id = (some_user) GROUP BY winner;
```

Comment: Wow, now I'm imagining hexagonal tennis courts (scoring would be very complex at the deuce and advantage levels) and football games with goals on all four sides rather than just two :-)

Answer (score 0):

I will have a user table (obviously), a Join table called Match with just match id and a transactional table that will have user_id, match_id, score. So for a particular match, there would be  two records corresponding to two user.

Also, I will also store a fk reference of the winning user_id in the match table. Just a quick way to find % of win for each user.